# validation of field having first two digits and one alphabet

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, validation

I've to develop a javascript code for validation of a text field. The last character must be either 'M' or 'D' or any digit between 0-9. The length of the field must not be greater than 3 characters.

eg. valid inputs are  8M or 25D or 110 or 45
The format of text field is like this::

1. if the last character is alphabet then it must be 'M' or 'D'
2. if the last character is M, the number must be less than 12 i.e 11M or 4M but not 12M or 13M
3. if the last character is D, the number must be less than 30 i.e. 1D or 15D or 25D but not 30D or 45D

How can I write javascript code for this validation? Please help.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFact" runat="server" AutoCompleteType="Disabled"  MaxLength="3" />
```

Comment: I am working on it. Surely give update as soon as possible

Comment: @SorangwalaAbbasali Thanks!!!

Comment: will M and D always in capitals?

Comment: Yes, I've made a CSS which accepts iinput in uppercase

Comment: Ok then  you will get the answer for this today for sure.

Comment: Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: @nischalinn this problem doesn't really seem like a regex one so I think you might have to write if-then statements. What about this?http://jsbin.com/budesofuta/edit?js,console

Comment: @bassxzero Thanks, I'll check it. But please will you post your code here as reply. That will be much better. Thank You!!!

Comment: @nischalinn I'm not sure it's what you wanted so, I'll post it if you say it works. and I'll explain it

Comment: @bassxzero let me check it

Answer (score 0):

@nischalinn

pls try following regex

```
var regexMD = /^((0?[1-9]|1[012])M|(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])D)$/;
 regexMD.test('01D');   //true
 regexMD.test('1D');    //true
 regexMD.test('32D');   //false
 regexMD.test('35D');    //false

 regexMD.test('01M');   //true
 regexMD.test('1M');    //true
 regexMD.test('13M');   //false
 regexMD.test('23M');    //false
```

Comment: Did you use some tool to generate this regex or did you write it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do Like this in jquery:
I tested and its working. If anything more you want just tell and i will add it.

```js
function findAns() {
    var i = 12, j = 30, id = "12M";
    var last = id.substr(id.length-1);
    var lengthOfString = id.length;
    var firsttwoCharacters = id.substr(0, 2);
    if (lengthOfString>2) {
        alert(firsttwoCharacters);
        if (last == "M") {
            if (i-firsttwoCharacters>0) {
                alert("OK");
            }
            else {
                alert("Not Ok");
            }
        }
        else if(last=="D") {
            if (j - firsttwoCharacters > 0) {
                alert("OK");
            }
            else {
                alert("Not Ok");
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        last = id.substr(id.length - 1)
        var firstChar = id.substr(0, 1);
        alert(firstChar);
        if (last == "M") {
            if (i - firstChar > 0) {
                alert("OK");
            }
            else {
                alert("Not Ok");
            }
        }
        else if (last == "D") {
            if (j - firstChar > 0) {
                alert("OK");
            }
            else {
                alert("Not Ok");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" name="name" value="Button click" onclick="javascript: findAns();" />
```

Comment: Actually no need to be tensed about this. just use the same script link and the function calling from your textArea and you will get your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Posting it as an answer per your request.

```
function validate(str){
  console.log('Testing:' + str);
  var number_regex = /^[1-9]\d*$/;

  if(str.length > 3){
    console.log('invalid length');
  }
  else if( str.slice(-1) === 'M' ){
    console.log('M case');
    var number_part = str.slice(0, -1);

    if( !number_regex.test(number_part) ){
      console.log('invalid input');
    }
    else if( +number_part > 11 ){
      console.log('invalid number part input');
    }
    else {
      console.log('valid input');
    }
  }
  else if( str.slice(-1) === 'D' ){
    console.log('D case');
    var number_part = str.slice(0, -1);

    if( !number_regex.test(number_part) ){
      console.log('invalid input');
    }
    else if( +number_part > 29 ){
      console.log('invalid number part input');
    }
    else {
      console.log('valid input');
    }
  }
  else if( number_regex.test(str)  ){
    console.log('all numbers case')
    console.log('valid input')
  }
  else {
    console.log('invalid input');
  }
}


validate('8M');
validate('asdf');
validate('asd');
validate('1M');
validate('12M');
validate('13M');

validate('0D');
validate('12D');
validate('29D');
validate('30D');

validate('301');
validate('001');
validate('999');
```